# Question mark operator for void void

Tags: operator-keyword

can somebody help
I am working in C# and I want to use ? : operator.
I do not need get solution status I only need play different sound for flushing/noFlushing button
My code is

```
var status = lSBControl.FlashConfirmButtonOnShowContentTab ? (override)                            
ExecutiveControl.Instance.IVDStateModel.TheIVDInterface.PlaySound(PA.HomeHelp.IVDGlobal.SystemSounds.ButtonClick)
ExecutiveControl.Instance.IVDStateModel.TheIVDInterface.PlaySound(PA.HomeHelp.IVDGlobal.SystemSounds.ButtonNoClick);
                 :
```

Comment: forget to say that problem is that if is true I do call void and if is a false then call void again and then I tried to put override but doesn't work. error said no void void

Answer (score 0):

The conditional operator can only be used with expressions that have values (of compatible types).

You need to use `if`/`else`.